Understanding lifetime across async
I have this rust program:
// src/main.rs
#![feature(async_closure)]

use std::error::Error;
use std::future::Future;

struct Foo {
    data: String,
}

impl Foo {
    pub async fn show<J, F>(&self, job: J) -> Result<F::Output, Box<dyn Error + '_>>
    where
        J: FnOnce(&mut String) -> F,
        F: Future,
    {
        let mut data = self.data.clone();
        let result = job(&mut data).await;
        Ok(result)
    }
}

async fn bar(object: &mut String) {
    assert_eq!(object, &mut "hey");
    ()
}


#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let foo = Foo { data: String::from("hey") };
    
    
    foo.show(async |_o: &mut String| {}).await;

    let result = foo.show(bar).await;
    
    assert_eq!(result.unwrap(), ());
    Ok(())
}

This won't compile:
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:33:38
   |
33 |     foo.show(async |_o: &mut String| {}).await;
   |                         -          - ^^ returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
   |                         |          |
   |                         |          return type of closure `{async closure body@src/main.rs:33:38: 33:40}` contains a lifetime `'2`
   |                         let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:35:18
   |
35 |     let result = foo.show(bar).await;
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ one type is more general than the other
   |
   = note: expected opaque type `impl for<'a> Future<Output = ()>`
              found opaque type `impl Future<Output = ()>`
   = help: consider `await`ing on both `Future`s
   = note: distinct uses of `impl Trait` result in different opaque types
note: the lifetime requirement is introduced here
  --> src/main.rs:13:35
   |
13 |         J: FnOnce(&mut String) -> F,
   |                                   ^

I'm trying to wrap my head around these errors.
The "lifetime may not live long enough" error seems out of place. There are no references in that closure. What could dictate the lifetime '2?
The "mismatched types" error is also hard for me to understand. Which lifetime requirement is being introduced there? What would the solutions to this compilation error look like?

All type parameters might be types that contain a lifetime (one of it's fields, …) and thus can have an invisible lifetime parameter. Only when you bind T: 'static you do know that your type parameter doesn't contain a lifetime that's not 'static.
